# cocoa http post request

Tags: objective-c, http, xcode4, httprequest

hello i know this has been asked and answered many times but i cant seem to understand how it works (im new to iphone dev & objective c in general)

i am trying to make a `create user` for my app. i have a file `create.php` on my server that expects to get a `_POST` variable called `id`. after it is called it `echo`s "DONE" for success and "EXIT" for failure.

i found some code and altered it (to the best of my knowledge) to fit my needs :

```
NSMutableString *tmpurl = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"http://mysite.com/"];
[tmpurl appendString:@"create.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:tmpurl];
NSString *uid = @"32478907348920437829078902347804930893741"; // should chenge for randome.
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id=%@", uid];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

now i don't know how to see what the page `echo`s back or even if it has reached it.

any information would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the NSURLConnection. Depending if you want to send this request synchronous or async, you may need to implement the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods.

Comment: umm i want the user to see "Loading" until it finishes how would you call that?

Comment: You can show a loading screen both ways. The work all takes the same amount of time. Async just allows more things to happen while you are waiting. I would look into AFNetworking or the old ASIHttpRequest. Those are both frameworks to help you out with your networking calls.

Comment: damn that complicated! do you know where i can find a GOOD and clear tutorial?

Comment: I recently added the ASI framework. It is no longer supported, but still works great. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use